# Integrate 1/|r-r'| in 3 dimensions

Tags: integration, volume, spheres

I would like to find the volume dependence of the following integrale
$$
I(V) = \int_V \text d^3 r \int_V \text d^3 r' \frac 1 {|\vec r - \vec r' |}
$$
Here $V$ is just a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ centered around the origin. I am sure that this is not so difficult with the right tool. But a simple substitution $ \vec r'' = \vec r' -\vec r$ does not help. Can someone help me out?

Comment: With the usual parameterisation this is $|B(1)|^2 \int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2y^2}{|x-y|} \ dxdy$

Comment: Where does this integration come from? What are $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$ ?

Answer (score 2):

For $V=B(r)$, with the usual parameterisation this is $|B(1)|^2$ times
\begin{align} \int_0^r\int_0^r \frac{x^2y^2}{|x-y|} \ dxdy
&= 2\int_{x=0}^r\int_{y>x}\frac{x^2y^2}{y-x}\ dydx\\ 
&= 2 \int_0^r x^2\int_{s=0}^{r-x}\frac{s^2+2sx+x^2}{s} \ dxds \\
&= 2 \int_0^r x^2\int_{s=0}^{r-x} s+2x+\color{red}{ \frac{x^2}{s}} \ dxds
\end{align}
The term in red doesn't integrate well at $s=0,x≠0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "doesn't  integrate well" means that it diverges... means that my integral does not exist?

Comment: Yes, another way to see it is $$\int_0^r \int_0^r \frac{x^2 y^2 dx dy }{|x-y|} ≥ \frac{r^4}{16} \int_{r/2}^r \int_{r/2}^r \frac{dxdy}{|x-y|}$$ and $1/|x|$ is not $L^1_{\text{loc}}$.